# How to customize how Array behaves in JavaScript by using Object.defineProperty method?

Tags: javascript

I want to change how Array behaves by using Object.defineProperty method.

I know this is not a good thing to do. This is just for an experiment purpose.

For example, if I have an array `[1, 2, 3]` and when I console.log([1, 2, 3]), I want the output result to be `[2, 4, 6]`.

Again, I know this is crazy thing to do! But, I want to understand how it works to understand JavaScript deeper.

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(
  Array.prototype,
  Symbol.iterator, //should this be `this` instead?
  {
    value: function*() {
      yield 'what should I do here ???';
    }
  }
)

console.log([1, 3]) // expect this result to be [2, 6]
```

## Thanks! - my final code

Thanks!! @Ry, @vol7ron

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    let originalIterator = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];

    Object.defineProperty(
        Array.prototype, 
        Symbol.iterator, 
        {
            value: function* () {
                for (let x of originalIterator.call(this)) {
                    yield 2 * x;                
                }
            }
        }   
    )

})();

console.log([...[1, 3]]);
```

Comment: So, the answer is it is not possible to do something like what I want to do? @vol7ron

Comment: To my knowledge.  Otherwise `function Array(){ ... }` could be created and used to inject damaging code every time some array (`['foo']`) was called.

Comment: yeah, that's true. malicious person can distribute a library that changes native object behavior to do something really bad.

Comment: @vol7ron could you post it as your answer. I think it's the answer.

Comment: Joe Walker discovered that vulnerability back in 2007

Comment: @vol7ron: What is a “primitive array” and what makes you think arrays don’t use `Array.prototype`

Comment: @Ry︁ it's what a moron says when they mean *array literal* :)

Comment: @vol7ron: Well, array literals are still regular arrays. They just stopped calling a constructor named `Array`/setting values using setters because that was always wrong.

Comment: Exactly, so I suppose I stand corrected and the prototype can still be used?  I stopped modifying those objects a long time ago and rely on others for vulnerability tests these days.  I'm curious why those aren't immutable.  It seems to me that if a person wants to extend them, they should make their own objects and call them, not modify something that is core.

Comment: @vol7ron: It would break backwards compatibility for a lot of websites. (As for why they weren’t always immutable… JavaScript is full of mistakes \o/)

Comment: Yep but with enough lead time, that can be mitigated; especially with transpilers and polyfills.

Comment: @shu please refer to Ry's answer

Comment: Don't need to credit me (I didn't contribute anything valuable) all @Ry and you already seemed to have most of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` doesn’t use iterator iteration to show your array. You *have* successfully overridden it in that example, though, as you can see with something that uses iterators, like array literal spread `[...[1, 3]]`.

Simplified:

```js
'use strict';

let originalIterator = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];

Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  for (let x of originalIterator.call(this)) {
    yield 2 * x;
  }
};

console.log([...[1, 3]]);
```

Comment: This is probably the most correct this answer will get

Comment: but now you are no longer using `Object.defineProperty` as originally stated

Comment: @vol7ron: I figured I’d simplify it. The code in the original question works fine with `[...[1, 3]]`.